# React-Select: Custom Styling for Options in SCSS-file

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-select

I use `reactjs@v18.2.0` and `react-select@v5.7.4`.

For the custom styling of the `react-select` component and some additional functionality, I created a custom functional component named `SelectInput.js`. As I wanted to keep all the css in my `SelectInput.module.scss`, I used the `classNames` property of `react-select`:

```
import Select from "react-select";
import styles from "./SelectInput.module.scss";

export default function SelectInput({options}) {
    function getClassNames() {
        return {
            container: () => styles.select_container,
            control: () => styles.input,
            menuList: () => styles.menu_list,
            option: () => styles.option,
        };
    }

    function getProps() {
        return {
            classNames: getClassNames(),
            options: options
        };
    }

    return (
        <Select { ...getProps() }/>
    );
}
```

This works fine for everything (`container`, `control`, `menuList`, `option`), but there is a problem with the properties of `option`.

An option can be hovered over, selected and focused. The hovering styles can be defined via a typical `&:hover` in the class `styles.option` from `SelectInput.module.scss`.

Unfortunately it is not possible to use `&:focus` or something for the focus or selected state. The only solution I found was to use the `styles` property of `react-select` which works, but the styling for the events need to be defined in the `SelectInput.js` file:

```
...
function getProps() {
    return {
        classNames: getClassNames(),
        options: options,
        styles: {
            option: (base, state) => {
                let newBase = { ...base };

                if (state.isFocused) {
                    newBase.backgroundColor = "#000000";
                } else if (state.isSelected) {
                    newBase.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
                }

                return newBase;
            }
        }
    };
}
...
```

This leads to defining styles in the component as well as in the scss-file which I would like to avoid.

**My Question:**
Is there a way to define the styling for the focus and selected events **only** in the scss file so that the styling stays completely there?